# create tables in tablespaces sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, create-table, tablespace

I was looking around the squelize website, but couldn't find a way to say that I can say that a table should be created in a differnt tablespace. (I am using Postgres as a database)

Is there any way I can do that? Or do I have to write all "Create Table" Statements by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by tablespace mean schema, you can pass that as an option when defining your model:

```
sequelize.define('model', {
  ...
}, {
  schema: 'whatever'
});
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference-Sequelize#define